Alternative ways to evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k+1)^2$
I'm looking for alternative ways to calculate $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k+1)^2$$
The normal approach is to expand $(2k+1)^2$ and use the formulas $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$ , $\sum_{k=1}^n k = \dfrac{n(n+1)}2$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n a = an$ as follow,
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k+1)^2&=4\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk^2\right)+ 4\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk\right)+\sum_{k=1}^n1\\
&=4\times \dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6 + 4\times \dfrac{n(n+1)}2+n\\&=\frac43n^3+4n^2+\frac{11}3n
\end{align}
But I think there are other ways to evaluate the sum. I had two ideas, but unfortunately couldn't develop them.
One idea is to use $\sum_{t=1}^n t^2 = \dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$ for $t=2k+1$ but I am not sure if this substitution works.
Another idea was to define $f(k)= (2k+1)^2$ and since $f(k)-f(-k)=8k$ we have $$\sum_{k=1}^n \left(f(k)-f(-k)\right)= 4n(n+1)$$
But I don't know how to continue this idea.
Edit:
I just noticed that I can continue the second idea by writing the function $f(k)$ as the sum of even and odd functions. But this method isn't much interesting and the original approach seems better.

If the result would be $n^3$ or something like that , this would indicate some pattern that can be exploited. But here, the expression exhibits no obvious structure so I would be surprised if there would be any reasonable alternative approach.

One pleasant alternative (although one can always quibble about how "alternative" it is) is to exploit the calculus of finite differences. This won't take long: write out the sequence of numbers $(2k+1)^2$ (you'll need only the first three, but I'll do five to make the point clearer), and then take successive differences:
$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} 
1 & & 9 & & 25 & & 49 & & 81 \\ 
& 8 & & 16 & & 24 & & 32 & \\
& & 8 & & 8 & & 8
\end{array}$$
where we stop once we hit a constant sequence. Then read off from the front numbers $1, 8, 8$ the identity
$$(2k + 1)^2 = 8\binom{k}{2} + 8\binom{k}{1} + 1\binom{k}{0}$$
and then read off the sum as
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{m-1} (2k+1)^2 = 8\binom{m}{3} + 8\binom{m}{2} + 1\binom{m}{1}.$$
This method always works, for any sequence $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ (I include $0 \in \mathbb{N}$). In other words, if you define the difference operator $\Delta$ on sequences by the formula
$$(\Delta(f))(n) := f(n+1) - f(n)$$
and let $\Delta^k$ denote the $k^{th}$ iteration of $\Delta$, then
$$f(n) = \sum_{k \geq 0} (\Delta^k f)(0) \binom{n}{k}$$
for all sequences $f$, and this is a discrete analogue of the MacLaurin expansion. The discrete analogue of integration, which we may call summation $\Sigma$, is the operator defined on sequences by
$$(\Sigma f)(0) = 0\qquad (\Sigma f)(m) = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} f(k)\;\;\; (m \geq 1),$$
and by Pascal's triangle (which says that for $f(n) = \binom{n}{k}$ we have $(\Delta f)(n) = \binom{n}{k-1}$), one easily derives
$$(\Sigma f)(n) = \sum_{k \geq 0} (\Delta^k f)(0) \binom{n}{k+1}.$$
The book Concrete Mathematics by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik has a wealth of material of this type.

Your alternative ideas don't work indeed. What you can do instead is
$$\sum_{k=1}^n(2k+1)^2=\sum_{j=2}^{2n+1}j^2-\sum_{i=1}^n(2i)^2$$
$$=\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)(4n+3)}6-1-4\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$$
$$=\frac{n(4n^2+12n+11)}3.$$

We can use the generating function to find the sum.
Let's consider $$ f(\alpha)=\sum_{k=1}^ne^{-\alpha(2k+1)}=e^{-\alpha}\frac{e^{-2\alpha}-e^{-2\alpha(n+1)}}{1-e^{-2\alpha}}=e^{-\alpha}\frac{1-e^{-2\alpha n}}{e^{2\alpha}-1}$$ We can decompose $f(\alpha)$ into the Taylor series:
$$f(\alpha)=A+B\alpha+C\alpha^2+...$$
It is clear that that our sum is
$$\frac{d^2}{d\alpha^2}f(\alpha)\,\bigg|_{\alpha=0}=\sum_{k=1}^n(2k+1)^2:=S$$
On the other hand,
$$\frac{d^2}{d\alpha^2}f(\alpha)\,\bigg|_{\alpha=0}=2C$$
It means that we have to find the coefficient $C$, decomposing $f(\alpha)$ at $\alpha\to0$ into the series.
$$e^{-\alpha}\frac{1-e^{-2\alpha n}}{e^{2\alpha}-1}=\frac{\big(1-\alpha+\frac{\alpha^2}2+O(\alpha^3)\big)\big(1-1+2\alpha n-\frac{4\alpha^2 n^2}2+\frac{8\alpha^3 n^3}6+O(\alpha^4)\big)}{2\alpha+\frac{4\alpha^2}2+\frac{8\alpha^3}6+O(\alpha^4)}$$
$$=n\big(1-\alpha+\frac{\alpha^2}2+O(\alpha^3)\big)\big(1-\alpha n+\frac{2\alpha^2 n^2}3+O(\alpha^3)\big)\big(1-\alpha-\frac{2\alpha^2}3+\alpha^2+O(\alpha^3)\big)$$
Grouping all the terms with $\alpha^2$
$$C=n\Big(\frac{11}6+2n+\frac23n^2\Big)$$
$$S=2C=\frac{n(11+12n+4n^2)}3$$

You can also make use of generating functions, although this particular method is cumbersome:
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^n(2k+1)^2&=\left[\sum_{k=1}^n(2k+1)^2x^{2k+1}\right|_{x=1}\\
&=\left[x\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left[x\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left[\sum_{k=1}^nx^{2k+1}\right]\right]\right|_{x=1}\\
&=\left[x\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left[x\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left[\frac{x^3(1-x^{2n})}{1-x^2}\right]\right]\right|_{x=1}\\
&=\left[x\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left[\frac{x^3((2n+1)x^{2(n+1)}-(2n+3)x^{2n}-x^2+3)}{(x^2-1)^2}\right]\right|_{x=1}\\
&=\left[\frac{x^3[(2n+1)^2x^{2n+4}-2(4n^2+8n+1)x^{2n+2}+(2n+3)^2x^{2n}-x^4+2x^2-9]}{(x^2-1)^3}\right|_{x=1}=\frac{0}{0}
\end{aligned}$$
Now we'll separate the resulting function into a product of one which isn't undefined at $x=1$ and another one which is, respectively:
$$\frac{x^3}{(x+1)^3}$$
and
$$\frac{(2n+1)^2x^{2n+4}-2(4n^2+8n+1)x^{2n+2}+(2n+3)^2x^{2n}-x^4+2x^2-9}{(x-1)^3}.$$
First limit yields $1/8$ and second one
$$\frac{8}{3}n(11+12n+4n^2)$$
Meaning
$$\sum_{k=1}^n(2k+1)^2=\frac{1}{8}\cdot\frac{8}{3}n(11+12n+4n^2)=\frac{n(11+12n+4n^2)}{3}$$

I'll join the party here. Using OP's described "normal approach" we know that the solution is a polynomial of degree three in $n$, so the formula is of the shape:
$$
\sum_{1\le k\le n}(2k+1)^2=\underbrace{an^3 + bn^2+cn +d}_{S(n)}\ .  
$$
The $S(n)-S(n-1)=(2n+1)^2$, and the value $S(0)=0$ fits into this recurrence, taking $n=1$. We use the particular values $0,1,2,3$ for $n$, and the resulted system has an easy equation, $d=0$, and for $a,b,c$ we have to solve:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\begin{bmatrix}
1^3 & 1^2 & 1\\
2^3 & 2^2 & 2\\
3^3 & 3^2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\b\\c
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
3^2\\3^2+5^2\\3^2+5^2+7^2
\end{bmatrix}
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
This gives, inverting the Vandermonde matrix of the system:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\b\\c
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1^3 & 1^2 & 1\\
2^3 & 2^2 & 2\\
3^3 & 3^2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
3^2\\3^2+5^2\\3^2+5^2+7^2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\frac 16
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & -3 & 1\\
-15 & 12 & -3\\
18 & -9 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
9\\34\\83
\end{bmatrix}
=\frac 13
\begin{bmatrix}
4\\12\\11
\end{bmatrix}
\ .
$$
So $S(n)=\frac 13(4n^3+12n^2+ 11n)$.

Check (or alternative proof, when the formula is known):
$$
\begin{aligned}
S(n+1)-S(n)
&=
\frac 13\Big(\ 4(3n^2+3n+1) +12(2n+1)+11(1)\ \Big)
\\
&
=\frac 13(12n^2+36n+27)
=(4n^2+12n+9)=(2n+3)^2\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
